# How to store array in mysql database using django model?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-serializer, django-mysql

1.I have array of products and want to store it in mysql database using django model.I tried with 'ListTextField' in models.py as below,

```
products = ListTextField(
        base_field=models.CharField(max_length=255),
        size=100,  # Maximum of 100 products in list
)
```

and I am using serializer to save data.But it is not working.

2.If I want to save data manually from views.py.How should I pass array of products in model object.for example,

```
obj=ContactDeatils(name='abc',products=['aa','bb'])
```

This gives me 'invalid syntax error' near products.

please help.

Comment: If you get an error, you should post the full message and traceback.

Comment: "I am using serializer to save data" - what do you mean?

Also I would recommend against using ListTextField, use JSONField if you can.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is error message ,                                     
        D:\Technologies\Python_Code\django_develops\django_development\kumo_soft\kumo_soft\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    from inventory import views
  File "D:\Technologies\Python_Code\django_develops\django_development\kumo_soft\inventory\views.py", line 146
    obj=new ContactDetails(companyName='aa',websiteUrl='aa',desc='cc',phoneNo='12222222',emailId='ss',address='aa',contactPersonNm='ff',designation='dd',companyType='fff',products= ['aaa','bbb'])
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AdamChainz serializer.py contains : from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ContactDetails 
class ContactDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactDetails 
        fields = ('companyName', 'websiteUrl', 'desc','phoneNo','emailId','address','contactPersonNm','designation','companyType','products')                                                                                 
and I am using this serliazer in views.py as,serializer = ContactDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
  serializer.save()

Comment: It worked with JSONField .Thanks for your suggestion @AdamChainz.